# Auto completion on gvim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Can we make gvim to only show autocomplete options without completing the word so that we can discard it if the expected completion option is not present?

The completeopt setting only seems to have longest match or complete the first option in the menu. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really good question and I would like to know if there's a setting that can be flipped to get what you mention.

A workaround/feature I use instead is hitting `CTRL + E` whenever you don't find a match you are looking for. This aborts the completion and takes you back to your original state.

Answer (score 1):

The `longest` option is what completes the word automatically. Drop it from your `completeopt` and you won't have this problem again.

For example:

```
set competeopt=menu,preview
```